# If starvation of processes is occurred, does it mean that there will be a deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, deadlock

If starvation of processes is occurred, does it mean that there will be a deadlock ???
Any explanation if yes, and if no ?!

Answer (score 1):

There are four **necessary and sufficient** conditions for a deadlock to occur (called Coffman conditions):

1. Mutual exclusion
2. Acquire and wait
3. No preemption
4. Circular wait

What you're asking is, essentially: **will a deadlock occur if there's only (albeit indefinite) *wait*?**. The answer is: no. All four conditions must be met in order for a deadlock to occur.

See more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

No, starvation does not imply deadlock. For illustration, consider two processes (`P`,`Q`) that share a resource which must must be handled with mutual exclusion.

The processes are controlled by the following program:

```
while ( true) {
  take();
  use();
  release();
}
```

It is possible that the system proceeds by letting `P` use the resource for any number of iterations, i.e. process `Q` starves for any period of time:

`P.take()` `P.use()` `P.release()` `P.take()` `P.use()` `P.release()` ...

but it is not a deadlock even if `Q` never gets a chance to access the resource.

Answer (score -1):

If two processes that need the same resource are starved in a certain way, there will be a deadlock. Let's  imagine a simple version of the Dining Philosphers Problem:

On a table are two individual chopsticks. Seated at the table are two philosophers. A philosopher may only eat his dinner by using both chopsticks.

Starvation will occur when each philosopher grabs one chopstick. Deadlock will occur when each philosopher waits patiently for the other to give them a chopstick.

Starvation will not occur when one philosopher grabs both chopsticks, eats, and passes the chopsticks to the other philosopher.

A way to fix this is to give resource-dominance to certain processes, so that there will be no deadlocks.

Continuing this example, this is as if the younger philosopher will always have to defer to the older philosopher if he wants a chopstick.